# Troubles converting double to LPARAM

Tags: c++, desktop-application

I am trying to make my first Windows Desktop Application (have used exclusively console until now). This is probably a real noob problem. I am making something for work that receives serial data from remote test equipment and logs/displays the data for trend analysis. I am having no trouble getting the data from the remote device and storing into a double (data is expected to be between 0.0000 and 0.9999).

I want to then take the data and display it in a `CreateWindow` Edit control using the following code:

```
hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, L"EDIT", L"0.000", 
                      WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | ES_LEFT | WS_TABSTOP, 
                      75, output_height, width, height, mainHandle, NULL,
                      (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLongPtr(mainHandle, GWLP_HINSTANCE), NULL);

SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SETTEXT, NULL, (LPARAM)/* insert num in some way*/);`
```

No matter how I try, I cannot find a way to convert double to `LPARAM`. I have tried every way I can think of find on the internet and none of them work. I'm working in Visual Studio Community 2019. Any help or tips is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
I am not very confident about programming windows, but It seems the WM_SETTEXT message would like to receive a string as the parameter, so you probably want to convert the double to string, using a swprintf() or something similar, then just casting it as (LPARAM) could work (my guess).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert double to string and cast string pointer to lparam:

```
double d_number;
wchar_t buffer[30];
swprintf(buffer, 30, L"%g", d_number);
SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SETTEXT, NULL, (LPARAM)buffer);
```

Comment: Why `swprintf` rather than `std::to_string`?

Comment: On the money! Thanks! I've been beating my head against this for hours.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Many reasons, but the forefront is he's going to soon decide he needs to fiddle with the format specifier, and this suddenly becomes the easiest way.